# calculate the combinatorial

Tags: code-golf

Given two integers - n and r, your task is to calculate the combinatorial nCr.

```
nCr = n! / r! (n-r)!
```

The caveat is that you have to write code to do this calculation in minimum number of characters.

Input 
The first line will be number of testcases T. Then T lines follow, each containing two positive integers - n and r.

output 
Print T lines, each line containing the value of nCr.

Constraints

```
1 <= T <= 100 
1 <= r <= n <= 1000
```

You can assume that the value nCr will fit into a signed 64 bit integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Golfscript, 31 characters

```
n%(;{~.@.@-]{1\,{)*}/}%~/\/}%n*
```

Explanation:

- `n/(;{...}%n*` splits the input by a newline, discards the first row (number of testcases), maps the rest and finally joins by a newline.

  - `~.@.@-` evals the input, rearranges it to `r n n r`, then subtracts `r` from `n`.
  - `]{...}%~` collects everything on the stack into and array, maps it and explodes the array

    - `1\,{)*}/` is the factorial function: push a `1` below the number, then create an array `0...n`, then for each element, multiply the accumulator by the value + 1. The map-reduce implementation is one char longer: `,{)}%{*}*`
  - `/\/` divides `n!` first by factorial of the difference, then by `r!`.

Comment: Hm, for input `1\n5 5\n` I get ` undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`. Am I misunderstanding the format of the input? :-/

Comment: no trailing newline please

Comment: Easily fixed by changing the first `/` to `%`.

Comment: Done, thanks. [tag:facepalm]